Subscribe to the number of subscribers (avoid polling)
In Redis, how can I subscribe to the number of subscribers to a given key (I want to know the number of connected users)? I'm aware of PUBSUB NUMSUB, but as far as I know it is not possible to subscribe to its value, and polling it every second seems like a huge waste of resource, especially if hundreds/thousands of clients are doing it simultaneously.

Generally no, pubsub is not persistent in the keyspace so you can't sub to it. 
You can add an internal logic on the app side to create and update an extra data-structure in the server for managing subs count yourself, which can be a bit of a challenging task since you need to track failover, disconnections etc. so you don't have false data. 
You can refactor to streams which give you better control options over groups and consumers, plus give you better stability.

Thanks a lot, it is indeed what I ended up doing. Actually, counting the number of subscription on redis's side would not even work, as my graphql server is clever enough to open a single subscription to redis even if many clients are connected. So I ended up adding a hook on ws.onConnect and ws.onDisconnect in my graphql server to add/remove elements on a hash table in redis (each server having their own entry with an expire time to account for cases where the server crashes (need redis 7.4.0 sadly but I'm sure other solutions exists)).

But what do you mean with streams? How would you use them here?

Stream does something similar to pub/sub but are easier to manage, you can group consumers, you can which consumers you have, and they dont fire and close, if a message didn't arrive to a consumer they aware of it. And since they are part of the key space you can add them as part of you tracking.

On the the TTL of keys in hash table, im actually currently design this feature to our library it'll be on the client side and Valkey will release it soon on the server side also. This functionality exists in one of the Java clients, bit the implementation is horrible, we start to work on it when a potential user complain on this feature in the mentioned client used local heap memory to track keys and ttl and consume 90% of the heap. We should release a much better implementation in our next release. Its actually a very bright algorithm, im very proud of the idea:)

You can check our client ValKey-Glide. The library available in Java, python and nodejs, cpp and go are under development.

ok thanks, I'll give it a look. My issue with streams is that I thought it was never forgiving previous messages, and often I just care about the latest message, but I'll see how it could help here.

Oh, I asked Valkey's (created a bug report upstream), and they just said they might implement it but they don't know when, good to hear there is some active progress here! And good to hear about your library, is it supposed to replace, e.g., ioredis for valkey?

Our goal is not to compete s I won't say replace, but we have years of experience with customers jave horrible issues with their clients, we learned through the years what are the issues and flaw's and decided that's its time to create a battle proven and bullet proof client. When the license change happened it got extra importance and we moved our library to Valkey organisations to be also the main client follow Valkey and not Redis, while almost all other main client are under redis org.

And currently we are able to prove we standing behind our goals. Last week i had to deal with two users, using the two main nodejs clients getting 7 and 9 minutes downtime when one nodes failover in memorydb. I did a huge amount of work to find a way workaround it, and when ran the same with our client without any special handling it worked flawless. If you are interested to chat with use and hear more you can find us in Valkey discord - https://www.linkedin.com/safety/go?messageThreadUrn=urn%3Ali%3AmessageThreadUrn%3A&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdiscord.gg%2FWt7n7NzfcZ&trk=flagship-messaging-android
